# How to launch UIViewController that is embedded in UINavigationController

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uitabcontroller

I have TabController with 2 tabs A &B 
Tab A: UINavigationController1-->Controller X--->Controller Y 
TAB B: UINaviagtionController2-->Controller A --->Controller B --->Controller C

In the Tab Controller, I have a button that I would like to launch Controller X.
How do I get X with its navigationBbarController? I can get to X, but doesn't show the navigation?

Thanks

Comment: Any takers? I thought this would be very easy?

Comment: right, how do I launch Tab A programatically while on TabController. Basically, the button is a shortcut to 'clicking Tab A', I know I can't segue to UINavigationController.